# Failed to get env details from Python API for /usr/bin/python3 without an error when executing jupyter notebook in Visual Studio

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, jupyter-notebook, julia

I have encountered a problem when trying to run a julia jupyter notebook in Visual Studio on Mac. Below is the output when I started the julia release kernel.

```
Visual Studio Code (1.85.2, undefined, desktop)
Jupyter Extension Version: 2023.11.1100101639.
Python Extension Version: 2023.22.1.
Pylance Extension Version: 2023.12.1.
Platform: darwin (arm64).
Workspace folder ~/Desktop/UBC/23W Term2/ECON 627/Problem Sets/codes, Home = /Users/heatherchen
17:07:38.926 [info] Start refreshing Kernel Picker (1706663258926)
17:07:38.930 [info] Using Pylance
17:07:40.147 [info] End refreshing Kernel Picker (1706663258926)
17:07:40.756 [info] Process Execution: ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/py312/bin/python -m pip list
17:07:40.795 [info] Start refreshing Interpreter Kernel Picker
17:07:40.795 [info] Start refreshing Kernel Picker (1706663260795)
17:07:43.348 [warn] Disposing old controller startUsingPythonInterpreter:'.jvsc74a57bd031f2aee4e71d21fbe5cf8b01ff0e069b9275f58929596ceb00d14d90e3e16cd6./usr/bin/python3./usr/bin/python3.-m#ipykernel_launcher' for view = 'jupyter-notebook'
17:07:43.349 [warn] Disposing old controller startUsingPythonInterpreter:'.jvsc74a57bd031f2aee4e71d21fbe5cf8b01ff0e069b9275f58929596ceb00d14d90e3e16cd6./usr/bin/python3./usr/bin/python3.-m#ipykernel_launcher (Interactive)' for view = 'interactive'
**17:07:43.350 [error] Failed to get env details from Python API for /usr/bin/python3 without an error**
17:07:44.353 [info] End refreshing Kernel Picker (1706663260795)
```

May I know how should I find this problem?

For your information, 'which python' returns

```
/Users/heatherchen/opt/anaconda3/envs/py312/bin/python
```

and 'which jupyter' return

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/jupyter
```

Comment: I do not have a Mac to test, however it seems like you have a mix of several Python versions and there might be a conflict between the system built-in Python and Anaconda Python (this is how I read your logs). The first good think to do would be to ensure that you can launch Jupyter via IJulia and perhaps that you can navigate across Jupyter kernells of your interest. This might involve running `Pkg.build("IJulia")` among others.